# c# return named tuple from linq join

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, tuples, nhibernate-envers

i'am trying to perform a join between a revision entity from nhibernate envers and a list with user names. i want to return a list of named tuples.

this is my code

```
public IEnumerable<(Societa company, DateTime datetime, string userName)> CompanyHistory()
{
    IAuditReader auditReader = this._session.Auditer();
    var revison = auditReader.CreateQuery().ForHistoryOf<Societa, RevisionEntity>().Results();
    IList<Persona> user = _session.QueryOver<Persona>().List();

    var query = revison.Join(user,
                        rev => rev.RevisionEntity.IdUtente,
                        us => us.Id,
                        (rev, us) => new
                        {
                            Oggetto = rev.RevisionEntity,
                            DataModifica = rev.RevisionEntity.RevisionDate.ToLocalTime(),
                            NomeUtente = us.NomePersona
                        }).ToList();
}
```

but now i didn't find a way to return the tuple

- cast didn't work
- ToValueTuple is not avaible to fro my query object

i try  also

```
(ele, p) => new (OutputGA Oggetto, DateTime DataModifica, string NomeUtente)
            {
                Oggetto = ele.RevisionEntity,
                DataModifica = ele.RevisionEntity.RevisionDate.ToLocalTime(),
                NomeUtente = p.NomePersona
            }).ToList();
```

but i got `new cannot be used with tuple type`

than

```
(ele, p) => new Tuple<OutputGA, DateTime, string>
            {
                Oggetto = ele.RevisionEntity,
                DataModifica = ele.RevisionEntity.RevisionDate.ToLocalTime(),
                NomeUtente = p.NomePersona
            }).ToList();
```

and got error about parameter not corresponding

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this

```
var tuples = data.Select(x => (A: x.A, B: x.B));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct syntax should be

```
(ele, p) => 
(
    Oggetto: ele.RevisionEntity,
    DataModifica: ele.RevisionEntity.RevisionDate.ToLocalTime(),
    NomeUtente: p.NomePersona
)).ToList();
```

Comment: in this way i get "The name Oggetto does not exist in the current context" and same for DataModifica and NomeUtente

Comment: I am not sure why you got this error. I guess it may be something related to the variable scope. As a reference, you may check the example I made on the [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qrRKBS) which should be able to compile with .NET Core 2.2.